# How Add a Save Button to Custom Meta Box without Leave/Stay js Dialog?

Tags: metabox

I remove the publish default button and add a custom submit button for the post page, but wordpress save it like a draft after showing the (js alert) dialog: "stay or leave the page?"

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is it not a question, but a solution!

Comment: Then please split it up into a question and an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE THE SOLUTION:
If you want remove the default publish button and use a custom submit button for your Custom Meta Box, you have to insert the submit_button in a `<div class="submitbox" id="submitpost"></div>` 
e.g.

```
<div class="submitbox" id="submitpost">
    <?php submit_button( 'Submit', 'primary', 'publish', false ); ?>
</div>
```